# How to show edit and delete buttons in single column in lightning datatable

Tags: lwc, lightning

I have requirement to show edit and delete button in single row rather than two different rows in lightning datatable of lwc.

Currently it is displaying as shown below

[image]

Instead of this want to display under one column like Action and have those buttons next to each other.

Also I dont want them in as shown below as it will result in increase in number of clicks

[image]

How can I achieve it?

Below is the code snippet for current scenario been showing up
[image]

```
{
   label:'Edit',
   type:"button-icon",
   typeAttributes:{
      name:'Edit',
      title:'Edit',
      iconName:'utility:edit'
   }
},
{
   label:'Delete',
   type:"button-icon",
   typeAttributes:{
      name:'Delete',
      title:'Delete',
      iconName:'utility:delete',
      iconClass:'slds-icon-text-error'
   }
}
```

Comment: You can use  <lightning-button-group> for this. Buttons will be shown side-by-side with an elegant UI.